# C# equivalent of Get-AppxPackage

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use C# to start a store app. This is how I do it in powershell.

Is it possible to do the same in C#? I don't want to just run the powershell command in C#.

```
$packageFamilyName = (Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'MYAPP' } `
                     | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PackageFamilyName);

Start-Process shell:appsFolder\$packageFamilyName!MYAPP;
```

Comment: consider adding a protocol handler for your app.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into how to add that in.